# VB How do I add items to a class list using iteration?

Tags: vb.net, list, class

This is a very simple question.

I am trying to add items to the Inventory class list from a .txt file. However i can't use the word 'New' in this line otherwise it give a syntax error:
New Inventory("Rod", 1)

```
Function GetInventory() As IEnumerable(Of Inventory)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(loc) = True Then
        If System.IO.File.ReadAllText(loc).Count > 0 Then
            Dim file As System.IO.StreamReader
            file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(loc)
            Do While file.Peek() >= 0
                New Inventory("Rod", 1)
            Loop

            Return New Inventory

            file.Close()
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

How do I go about this???
Thank you.

Comment: it should be as easy as adding as simple `yield` statement: `yield new Inventory("Rod", 1, 50)` ;)

Comment: this returns an error: 'Yield is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level'. Thanks for quick response, though.

Comment: you arent qualifying what you read from the file, so you could just add it to a list that you return.  if the method is meant to add to an existing list, return `newList.ToArray()` so you can use AddRange the return

Comment: Don't do the `.Exists()` check. Just handle the exception if it fails. Also, this function probably is the wrong place to handle the exception... meaning you can get rid of the error checking here entirely.

Comment: what version of vb.net are you using? `yield` should be there [since 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156729.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you have, you're reading the entire file into memory twice. That's crazy wasteful.

Also, you don't need the `.Exists()` check here. The file system is *volatile*, meaning it's possible for the file to cease to be available between when you check `.Exists()` and when you try to access the file. A good program will still have a good exception handler for when the file does not exist, and now that you have an exception handler, the `.Exists()` check is just redundant. It's not saving you the performance hit you likely think it is. Also, this method is probably the wrong place to handle the exception. That's usually better to do in the calling code somewhere, meaning you can skip error checking here completely.

You can get this whole method down to a single statement that will cut your execution time in half:

```
Function GetInventory(ByVal loc As String) As IEnumerable(Of Inventory)
    Return IO.File.ReadLines(loc).Select(Function(i) New Inventory(i, 1))
End Function
```